# Does the jquery mobile and angular js conflicts dangerously?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-mobile

i am planning to develop an application using jquery mobile and angular js together. When i searched somewhere i have seen that it is not prefered. Does it so? it conficts in most of the cases??? someone could help me?

Comment: You don't need mix it with jquery mobile .. for ui you can use either angular  UI or jquery mobile css

Comment: moreover if you wanna use angular .. Then try ionic framework instead of jquery mobile .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It conflicts in many cases. But the thing is there is many other ways to do the same function u required. I have done some apps with mobile jquery and angularJS.